# PDF creation in React using '@react-pdf/renderer'

Tags: reactjs, pdf, multilingual, hebrew, react-pdfrenderer

I have a question about PDF creation in React using '@react-pdf/renderer'. I'm trying to create a PDF document that contains multi-language strings with Hebrew and English combined (or solely Hebrew or English). I've changed the document's font to "Rubik" to display Hebrew characters. However, for multi-language strings, the text appears mixed up and misplaced.
It seems that the  component does not support the 'direction' attribute, neither as a property nor as a style. I'm starting to think that this library might not fully support Hebrew. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

I tried using bidi tag, Unicode prefixes without success.